# How to get the number of edit-texts that are present in the screen using UI-Automator in android

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

**What I am trying to do:**

- There are 2 edit-texts in a linear layout as shown, how to get the
  number of edit-texts in the screen.
- Any samples documentation on UI-automater

---

**ExampleInstrumentedTest.java**

```
package com.testing.espressodemo;

import android.support.test.filters.SdkSuppress;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.By;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject2;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.Until;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    private UiDevice mDevice;

    @Before
    public void startMainActivityFromHomeScreen() {

        // Initialize UiDevice instance
        mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        // Start from the home screen
        mDevice.pressHome();
        // Wait for the Apps icon to show up on the screen
        mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.desc("Apps")), 3000);
        // Once you have a reference to the Apps icon, invoke the click method to simulate a click.
        UiObject2 appsButton = mDevice.findObject(By.desc("Apps"));
        appsButton.click();
        // Wait for the Calculator icon to show up on the screen
        mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("EspressoDemo")), 3000);
        //Use the findObject and click methods to obtain a reference to the Calculator icon and simulator a click.
        UiObject2 calculatorApp = mDevice.findObject(By.text("EspressoDemo"));
        calculatorApp.click();


    }

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {

       // Finding the number of EditText Views

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.testing.espressodemo.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonId"
        android:text="click"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you need the count?  Or are you trying to predetermine the index/instance of each?

Comment: I just trying to Get the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

1. Add an id to the LinearLayout that contains the EditText fields

   `LinearLayout android:id="@+id/edit_text_container"`
2. In your UiAutomator test do a getChildCount() on the Linear Layout and save the value
   `UiObject editTextContainer = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .resourceId("com.testing.espressodemo:id/edit_text_container);
                                                                                         int editTextCount = editTextContainer.getChildCount();`